# ngrx selector not returning number but returning the entire state object instead

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-selectors

I'm trying to make this feature selector to work. But instead of returning a number the selector returns the entire state object (in my case the CounterState)

Here is a my working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ctypd1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcounter.selectors.ts

I get the following outout on the page: `Current Count: [object Object]`

I get the following output in the console.

```
{counter: 1, loaded: true, loading: false}
{counter: 2, loaded: true, loading: false}
{counter: 3, loaded: true, loading: false}
```

I was expecting just `1,2,3` What am I missing?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're creating a nested tree structure while registering the reducer.

```
StoreModule.forFeature(counterFeatureKey, { counter: counterReducer }),
```

This should be (or the selector needs to be tweaked):

```
StoreModule.forFeature(counterFeatureKey, counterReducer ),
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there any documentation on the difference between the two?
And you need to tweak the selector, how would you tweak the selector to make it work?

Comment: If you install and use the ngrx devtools you can inspect the state tree, which should help for these issues. If keep the feature as before, you have to select the state with state.counter.counter

Comment: I adjusted the selector to the following:
`export const counterSelector = createSelector(
  selectCounterFeature,
  state => state.counter.counter
);`
But then I receive the following error:
`Property 'counter' does not exist on type 'number'.`

See https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sw798a?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcounter.selectors.ts

So I don't really understand it

Comment: Had a similar issue with setting my reducer inside a []. This answere saved me a lot of time.